# drawCircle of Android's canvas draws not a circle

Tags: java, android, canvas, geometry

I'm trying to draw a circle on my canvas. Pseudocode of my algorithm looks like that

```
double R = 1.0;
// Draw 11 points, lying on the circle with the radius of 1
// and angle from 0 to 90 degrees
for(int i=0; i<=10; i++)
{
    drawPoint( R*cos(PI*i/20), R*sin(PI*i/20) );
}
// Draw a circle with center at the (0; 0) and with the radius of 1
drawCircle(0, 0, R);
```

That's what I've got:

[image: That's what I've got]

Looks fine, but there is one problem. When I increase radius only points with angles 0, 45 and 90 lie on a circle.

That's how it looks 72 degrees:

[image: That's how it looks: 72]

There is no any info about accuracy of the method drawCircle on **developer.android.com**.
I guess that it draws, based on the values at points with angles 0, 45, 90, ..., and calculate line in other positions very approximately.

I know, that I can draw circle as accurate as I want to, if I'll draw it like a polyline with tiny step, but it will work very slow.

So I want to find out - is there any methods to draw circle accurate in Android?

**UPD 1:**

How do I draw a points:

```
int x, y;
x = getPixelX(point.getX());
y = getPixelY(point.getY());
canvas.drawCircle(x, y, point.radius, paint);
```

Where **getPixelX** and **getPixelY** takes a coorditate of the point on plane and returns the same coordinate on the screen, basing on scale and offset.

I thought that I could make some mistake in those methods, but they work perfectly with the lines. I can zoom in lines and there is no error, all the points lies just on the line.

**UPD 2:**

There are comments, that probably I make a mistake in my calculations. I do not argue, perhaps you're right. So here is my "calculations".

How do I zoom in:

```
public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
    // zoomQ is 0.9 or 1.1
    double zoomQ  = (e.getWheelRotation() + 10) / 10.0;
    scaleX *= zoomQ;
    scaleY *= zoomQ;
}
```

How do I move the plane:

```
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

    centerX -= (e.getX() - lastMouseX)/scaleX;
    centerY -= (e.getY() - lastMouseY)/scaleY;

    lastMouseX = e.getX();
    lastMouseY = e.getY();
}
```

How do getPixelX/Y works:

```
public int getPixelX(double planeX) {
    return (int)Math.round( scaleX*(planeX - centerX) + ScreenWidth/2 );
}

public int getPixelY(double planeY) {
    return (int)Math.round( scaleY*(planeY - centerY) + ScreenHeight/2 );
}
```

Comment: excuse my question, but when i look at your images i can't really detect a circle - can you tell my yur zoom factor? i mean: whats the distance between your point and the circle (d) using what radius (r)... seems like a rounding error to me...

Comment: Chances are that your code has some bugs in it. Please post your draw methods as well.

Comment: At the very least, I'd like to see the `drawPoint` method. I assume the `drawCircle` one is fine if it works for 0, 45, and 90.

Comment: It would be a great news if it's my fault! :) Well, drawPaint just draw circle like that
                    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, point.radius, paint);

Comment: could you change `R*cos(PI*i/20)` to `R*cos(PI*i/20.0)` and try again?

Comment: Sure! Nothing has changed.

Comment: Now the question is: Is drawCircle off or your calculation for the points ^_^

Comment: Yeah, but, as I wrote - my calculations are correct for lines. But anyway, I'll check my calculations again, just in case.

Comment: Maybe I got confused, but why you wrote 20 instead of 180 here: `PI*i/20`

Comment: I don't understand the second image. Why is it a seemingly a straight line, just how much have you increased the radius by?

Comment: I increase the radius of 200-300 times. And I wrote 20 instead of 180 because Math.sin and cos works with radians, not with degrees. Actually it is PI/2/10*i. PI/2 is a first quarter of circle (from 0 to 90 degrees).

Comment: I tried to look up the code for drawCircle. Unfortuntely it links to native code([see here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/4.4_r1-robolectric-0/android/graphics/Canvas.java#Canvas.drawCircle%28float%2Cfloat%2Cfloat%2Candroid.graphics.Paint%29)) so no help there.